# DataGrid columns is not loaded at first time in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, datagrid, wpf-controls

I tried to fill the datagrid view but its not working properly the first time.

In DataGrid View Columns are not updated. The first time the datagrid column is zero and the second time the column count is updated correctly.

```
//_dtsource is nothing but DataView
Dgrid.ItemsSource = _dtsource;

Dgrid.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
Dgrid.Columns[1].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
Dgrid.Columns[2].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

XAML Code :

```
<Grid Height="642" Width="835">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="283,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Access Permissions" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Height="23" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,68,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="List Of Forms :" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="23"/>
            <DataGrid x:Name="Dgrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,111,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="815" Height="353" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" SelectionChanged="Dgrid_SelectionChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>

        </Grid>
```

Comment: Post your XAML code for the datagrid

Comment: Yes, i update my question please help me friend i m new for wpf

Comment: I m using here moden ui

Comment: I dont see any columns in your datagrid

Comment: Ya but in item source i pass dataview may be that having columns\

Comment: Then set your AutoGenerateColumns="False" to be True

Comment: Ya i changed it also its not working i will pass data table then also its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59483/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-dinesh).